# Convert a string to datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, casting

This timestamp is saved to the table as a string. How do I convert it to a datetime type when querying the table?

For instance:

```
declare @timestamp as nvarchar
set @timestamp ='20130319092507.000000-000'
```

I have tried `convert(datetime, timestamp, *n*)` and `cast(timestamp as datetime)`

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: [Why do you not specify a length for your `nvarchar` parameter?](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx) Why should it be `nvarchar`? Do you think you will have timestamps with umlauts and pound signs?

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion: fix your table! Stop storing date/time values as strings. Nothing good can come of that. For example the column could have `20130231` or `Hallowe'en` or `This is not a date` and you now have to filter those out. In addition to inherent validation, you also lose the ability to perform date operations.

```
DECLARE @timestamp VARCHAR(32);
SET @timestamp = '20130319092507.000000-000';

SELECT CONVERT
(
  DATETIME, 
  LEFT(@timestamp, 8) + ' ' 
  + STUFF(STUFF(SUBSTRING(@timestamp,9,6),3,0,':'),6,0,':')
);
```